# How many photos should exist on my MBP?

Tags: google-photos

I recently downloaded Google Photos Backup and let it run with default settings.  It is currently telling me that I have 76,170 photos to back up.  I definitely haven't taken 76K photos on a camera, could this number be correct?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to programming and much more of a product specific user support question.

Comment: I'm ok with that - is there a better place to ask the question?